# Plone rich text tile tries to load incorrect js URL for TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, plone

- Plone 4.2.1.1
- plone.tiles 1.2
- plone.app.tiles 1.0.1
- plone.app.blocks 1.0
- plone.app.drafts 1.0a2
- Products.TinyMCE 1.2.15

I have a Plone site with two rich text tiles on a page, created following [Using tiles to provide more flexible Plone layouts](http://glicksoftware.com/blog/using-tiles-to-provide-more-flexible-plone-layouts).

The problem is that when editing the tiles, TinyMCE will not load.

In Firebug on the Net tab I see a whole slew of 404s that look like this:

```
http://example.com/en/front-page/@@edit-tile//plugins/pagebreak/editor_plugin.js
```

By comparison, I know that the correct URLs should look like this:

```
http://example.com/portal_javascripts/MyTheme/plugins/xhtmlxtras/editor_plugin.js
```

When I set my portal_javascripts in Development Mode, it works, but when I turn Development Mode off, that's when I see this problem.

So apparently it's due to some kind of javascript conflict, but I don't know where to look for it.

I really need to solve this problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Additional information:

When portal_javascripts has development mode turned off, the condition in this line is never true: https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/blob/1.2.x/Products/TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/tiny_mce_src.js#L47

That's because the tiny_mce.js file is merged with other files and the name is randomized, and so looking it up by name will always fail.  Consequently, the `baseURL` property of the `tinymce` object will not be set in `init`.
Instead, `baseURL` ends up being set here:
https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/blob/1.2.x/Products/TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/tiny_mce_src.js#L8397

This is where the URL `http://example.com/my-page/@@edit-tile/` is used for `baseURL`.

I verified this by turning off merging and caching in portal_javascripts, but leaving development mode off.  Then it works, because it finds `tiny_mce.js` by name.

Also, I found that when it fails, all of TinyMCE's plugins are added as explicit `<script>` elements in the head of the iframe (with the `@@edit-tile` URLs, which can't be loaded).  By contrast, when it works, all the plugins are loaded here:
https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/blob/1.2.x/Products/TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/tiny_mce_src.js#L8458

IOW, they are not added explicitly to the iframe as `<script>` elements.

(In case I wasn't clear, when I mention iframe, I'm talking about the tile's editing overlay, not TinyMCE's.  There is an iframe inside an iframe....)

Comment: Does the page that includes TinyMCE have its <base> tag set up correctly?

Comment: The <base> tag looks like this:  <base href="http://mysite.com/en/front-page">.  The page that has the tiles is the site's home page.  Each language root's home page is set up the same way with its own tiles, i.e. fr/front-page, es/front-page, ar/front-page.